# can you use a discord.js embed in random-puppy url function

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js

```
if(command === "meme"){
    var x = `${args}`;
    if(!args[0]){var x = "meme";}

    meme(`${x}`)
    .then(url =>{
      const eee = url
    }) 

    const ss = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       .setAuthor(client.user.username, client.user.avatarURL)
       .setColor(0x00ffff)
       .setImage(`${eee}`);

      message.channel.send({ss});   
  }
```

when i put the embed inside `(url =>{})` nothing happens when i activate the command, and if i put it outside it says my `const` is not defined is there a way to use the data from the `url` variable outside `(url =>{})`

Comment: hello, what its `url` in you code? its message content or what?
the 1 way its `let url;` at begin of the block and then  write `eee = url`. But i think better rewrite your code so that it is more understandable and logical.
And class Discord.MessageEmbed() used only for read embeds, for send you need use `new Discord.RichEmbed()`

Comment: @Cipher it is from the module "random-puppy" and i assume its a random image url from reddit on imgur

Answer (score 0):

I think this code must work right, if you function "meme" dont returned an undefined value.

```
if(command === "meme"){
    let searchImage = 'meme';
    if(args.length > 0) {
         searchImage = args[0];
    }

    let findImage = meme(searchImage);
    if(!findImage) {
        console.log('Fuction returned undefinded value');
        return;
    }

    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
       .setAuthor(client.user.username, client.user.avatarURL)
       .setColor(0x00ffff)
       .setImage(findImage)
    message.channel.send(embed);
}
```